# Online leaderboards for iPhone games

Tags: iphone, leaderboards

I'd like to add an online leaderboard to my iPhone game.  Upon discovering the time and effort required to create a Game Center account I started considering other options.

What do you use for online leaderboards?  Why?

I'm open to a variety of options including App Engine, using EC2, Open Feint, PlusPlus etc.

-- I'd like to make this a community wiki but I don't see the option.

Comment: Community Wiki is a mod-only feature now.  I see no reason in particular to make this post CW, since I would hope the answers would be more "why" rather than just a list of answers.

Comment: What was the problem with starting a Game Center account? Do you mean for the player? For the developer, I only remember it taking a few seconds (seriously, I think you just press the button in iTunes Connect).

Comment: Closing this now as it's a "which tech to use" question.  Actually this is a perfect example of why these kinds of questions are closed, since the accepted answer is no longer valid as OpenFeint is now shut down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for OpenFeint, it is easy to use. Why I say that? Well, because even *I* managed to do it XD!

OpenFeint accepts achievements, leaderboards and other stuff I didn't pay much attention to. Also, if you make a decent game, the site seems to focus a lot on helping you advertise your game, making it a "free app download" for one day in the site and in another iPhone games site. It *really* drags a lot of people's attention to your game.

A lot of games use OpenFeint, so the community is decently big, and remember: players are hungry for the achievement points they get in games.

Of course, with Game Center out, a lot of people is implementing it into their games, so you still might want to give it a go.

Comment: Worth noting now that OpenFeint has been subsumed into Gree, which is a far more elaborate bells and whistles platform than OpenFeint, and seems to be centred around their virtual store. For me at least, that's reason to go back to just using Game Center, and something else Android specific if you want cross platform support.